# Textbox not diaplying nullable decimal MVC2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I have this code in the viewpage

```
<%= Html.TextBox(Model.amount.Value.ToString())%>
```

The "amount" as indicated above is nullable decimal. Here is the model defined,

```
Public class route {
public decimal? amount {get; set;}
}
```

on executing the textbox doesnot display any value ? How can I get the textbox to display the value.

Answer (score 0):

Try `<%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.amount)%>`